# php array into update sql

Tags: php, arrays, list, associative

[image]i have an array as above. The even string are the uniqueId and odd strings are the values. i would like to convert this into update sql i.e .update table set value=$value and id=$id. but the problem is how to convert the odd string as id and even string as value. how do i convert the above array into executable sql.

i have tried json_encode, which gets me comma separated values. i tried explode, but it didnot work. appreciate every suggestion.but none seems to have worked

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Split array into chunks of size 2:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($yourArray, 2);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo $chunk[0] . '; ' . $chunk[1];
    // perform insert
}
```

Comment: oh Wow, thanks u_mulder for quicker response and a perfectly working solution